# Convert sql command to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

Please help convert this SQL command to LINQ:

```
SELECT TOP(5) Tbl_News.*  
FROM Tbl_News 
INNER JOIN Tbl_Comments ON Tbl_News.id=Tbl_Comments.News_Id 
GROUP BY
    Tbl_News.Id, Tbl_News.Title, Tbl_News.Explanation,
    Tbl_News.Body, Tbl_News.Image, Tbl_News.Date, 
    Tbl_News.Categories_Id, Tbl_News.User_Id, Tbl_News.Active, Tbl_News.Visits 
ORDER BY
    COUNT(Tbl_News.Id) DESC
```

Thanks

Comment: Please describe what your target is. What should be the output - expected result data? Please provide your table structure too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that this is the only SQL expression you need to convert- you can use [Linqpad](https://www.linqpad.net/) to convert your query and make adjustments as you go if you run into issues you didn't foresee when asking this question. Here is a stab at what you are trying to do:

```
(from news in Tbl_News
join comments in Tbl_Comments on news.id equals comments.News_Id
group news by Tbl_News.Id into idGroup
let count = idGroup.Count()
orderby count
select news).Take(5)
```

I'm not sure what the benefit of the other group members is in your query- I don't know that you need them.

Comment: Thank you, it was useful